# Streaming JSON objects using akka http chunked response

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Is it abuse or somehow dangerous to use akka-http like this?

On server

```
def source(consumerOffset: UUID) = 
  readJournal.eventsByTag(“MyTag", consumerOffset).map(_.asJson)

pathPrefix("stream" / Segment.map(UUID.fromString)) { offset =>
  pathEndOrSingleSlash {
    get {
      complete {
        HttpResponse(
          StatusCodes.OK,
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, source(offset))
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then on client side

```
Source.single(HttpRequest("http://localhost:9000/stream"))
  .mapAsync(1) { r =>
    Http().singleRequest(r).map { res =>
      res.entity.dataBytes.map(_.parse[Event])
    }
  }
  .flatMapConcat(identity).mapAsync(processEvent)
```

**UPD:**

1. Is it guaranteed that chunks I send will be the same on client side.
2. Is it ok to have response with possibly endless number of chunks?
3. What is the right Content-Type for this kind of response?

**UPD 2:**

Akka 2.4.9 added ability to respond with streams. And basically does exactly the same, providing some syntax sugar.
See the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/http/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html).

Comment: Which part are you concerned about?  It all appears to be boiler plater at first glance...

Comment: 1. Is it guaranteed that chunks I send will be the same on client side.

Comment: 2. Is it ok to have response with possibly endless number of chunks?

Comment: I've updated question.

Comment: @DenisMikhaylov In addition to this, What happens if the Client closes the connection in b/w, but server has no possible way to know it, server thinks the client is just slow in consuming and it keeps buffering the response. How to handle these scenarios?

Comment: @curious There is an `idle connection timeout` setting for such scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions in order:

1. Yes, the client will receive `BytesString` representations of your objects encoded in json.
2. Yes, it is fine to have a stream source on the server side which never terminates.
3. The content you've specified in the question (`application/json`) is correct.